# How to copy entire folder from Amazon EC2 Linux instance to local Linux machine? 

Tags: linux, ssh, amazon-ec2, sftp, scp

I connected to Amazon's linux instance from ssh using private key. I am trying to copy entire folder from that instance to my local linux machine .

Can anyone tell me the correct `scp` command to do this?

Or do I need something more than `scp`? 
Both machines are Ubuntu 10.04 LTS

Comment: Probably better suited for http://askubuntu.com, but depending on what you need to do, there are multiple ways to do it. You can use bare `scp` like `scp -r user@remotehost:/path/to/directory /path/to/local` to copy a directory from a remote machine to your local. If you need to keep directories in sync, you can use `rsync`.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Call `scp` from client machine with recursive option:

```
scp -r user@remote:src_directory dst_directory
```

Comment: this solution helped actually i was trying to copy data without using private key.. scp -i *.pem -r user@remote:src_directory dst_directory

Answer (score 88):

another way to do it is

```sh
scp -i "insert key file here" -r "insert ec2 instance here" "your local directory"
```

One mistake I made was `scp -ir`. The key has to be after the `-i`, and the `-r` after that.

so

```sh
scp -i amazon.pem -r ec2-user@ec2-##-##-##:/source/dir /destination/dir
```

Comment: Finally, an answer that includes the -i part. This worked, thanks!

Comment: I had a error when i tried to do this: `Load key "key.pem": bad permissions`. I've solved by typing `chmod 400 key.em`.

Answer (score 16):

```
scp -i {key path} -r ec2-user@54.159.147.19:{remote path} {local path}
```

Comment: Please try to avoid just dumping code as an answer and try to explain what it does and why. Your code might not be obvious for people who do not have the relevant coding experience.

Comment: yes, While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 7):

For EC2 ubuntu

go to your .pem file directory

```
scp -i "yourkey.pem" -r ec2user@DNS_name:/home/ubuntu/foldername ~/Desktop/localfolder
```

Answer (score 3):

You could even use rsync.

```
rsync -aPSHiv remote:directory .
```

Answer (score 2):

This's how I copied file from amazon ec2 service to local window pc:

```
pscp -i "your-key-pair.pem" username@ec2-ip-compute.amazonaws.com:/home/username/file.txt C:\Documents\
```

For Linux to copy a directory:

```
scp -i "your-key-pair.pem" -r username@ec2-ip-compute.amazonaws.com:/home/username/dirtocopy /var/www/
```

To connect to amazon it requires key pair authentication.

Note:

Username most probably is ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

I use sshfs and mount remote directory to local machine and do whatever you want. [Here](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/8904) is a small guide, commands may change on your system

Answer (score 1):

This is also important and related to the above answer.
Copying all files in a local directory to EC2. This is a Unix answer.

Copy the entire local folder to a folder in EC2:
`scp -i "key-pair.pem" -r /home/Projects/myfiles ubuntu@ec2.amazonaws.com:/home/dir`

Copy only the entire contents of local folder to folder in EC2:
`scp -i "key-pair.pem" -r /home/Projects/myfiles/* ubuntu@ec2.amazonaws.com:/home/dir`

Answer (score 0):

I do not like to use scp for large number of files as it does a 'transaction' for each file.  The following is much better:

```
cd local_dir; ssh user@server 'cd remote_dir_parent; tar -c remote_dir' | tar -x
```

You can add a `z` flag to tar to compress on server and uncompress on client.

Answer (score 0):

One way I found on youtube is to connect a local folder with a shared folder in EC2 instance. Please view this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bSabC1Rz46E) for the full instruction. The sharing is instantaneous.